# Getting obj from array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, object, salesforce, soql

I have the below response from a SalesForce API query that I am trying to work with. I cannot seem to figure out how to capture any of the information regarding the [Tasks] obj. in PHP. See below for API response & existing code.
As you can see below, I can work with the account information, but not the Task info.

```
$query ="SELECT accountId,Status,Id,Service_Account_DMKT__r.name,(select id,Activity_Type__c,ActivityDate from Case.Tasks) from case where Service_Account_DMKT__r.name='budcrossfordfd' AND Owner.Name ='".$name."' AND CreatedDate = THIS_MONTH AND Record_type_name__c='Performance Reviews' AND status NOT IN ('')";
$response = $mySforceConnection->query($query);
$queryResult = new QueryResult($response); //We collected the response from our SF Query
$counter=0;    
for ($queryResult->rewind(); $queryResult->pointer < $queryResult->size; $queryResult->next()) {
  $counter++;
  $accountId = $queryResult->current()->AccountId; //Pulls accountId from Query
  $accountName=$queryResult->current()->Service_Account_DMKT__r->Name; //pulls the name of the account the case exists on, note that when we use XXX__r.XXX, we sep. this in PHP with ->
  $caseId= $queryResult->current()->Id; //Pulls CaseId from Query
  $taskType=$queryResult->current()->Tasks->Activity_Type__c; //Pulls the Type of the Task that exists under the Case (This isn't working!)
  $taskId= $queryResult->current()->Tasks->Id; //Pulls Task Id (This isn't Working!)
  $taskDate=$queryResult->current()->Tasks->Activity_Date; //Pulls date the Task was Created (This isn't Working!)
  echo'<p>AccountId=' . $accountId . '</p>';
  echo'<p>accountName=' . $accountName . '</p>';
  echo'<p>caseId=' . $caseId . '</p>';
  echo'<p>taskType=' . $taskType . '</p>';
  echo'<p>taskId=' . $taskId . '</p>';
  echo'<p>taskDate=' . $taskDate . '</p>';
}
```

Response :

```
Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in Z:\web\phpToolKit\test\partner.php on line 65



Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in Z:\web\phpToolKit\test\partner.php on line 66



Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in Z:\web\phpToolKit\test\partner.php on line 67

AccountId=0016000000NsN3uAAF

accountName=budcrossfordfd

caseId=5000e00001J7KtpAAF

taskType=

taskId=

taskDate=

QueryResult Object
(
    [queryLocator] => 
    [done] => 1
    [records] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [type] => Case
                    [Id] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 5000e00001J7KtpAAF
                            [1] => 5000e00001J7KtpAAF
                        )

                    [any] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 0016000000NsN3uAAFClosed - Approved5000e00001J7KtpAAF
                            [Service_Account_DMKT__r] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [type] => Account
                                    [Id] => 
                                    [any] => budcrossfordfd
                                )

                            [Tasks] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [done] => 1
                                    [queryLocator] => 
                                    [records] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                                (
                                                    [type] => Task
                                                    [Id] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => 00T0e00006GH5Q2EAL
                                                            [1] => 00T0e00006GH5Q2EAL
                                                        )

                                                    [any] => Call - Outbound2018-04-04
                                                )

                                            [1] => stdClass Object
                                                (
                                                    [type] => Task
                                                    [Id] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => 00T0e00006GGNgEEAX
                                                            [1] => 00T0e00006GGNgEEAX
                                                        )

                                                    [any] => 
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [size] => 2
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [size] => 1
    [pointer] => 1
    [sf:QueryResult:private] => 
)
```

I've also tried:

```
foreach($queryResult->records as $case){     
  $accountId = $queryResult->current()->AccountId; //Pulls accountId from Query
  $accountName=$queryResult->current()->Service_Account_DMKT__r->Name; //pulls the name of the account the case exists on, note that when we use XXX__r.XXX, we sep. this in PHP with ->
  $caseId= $queryResult->current()->Id; //Pulls CaseId from Query     
  echo'<p>AccountId=' . $accountId . '</p>';
  echo'<p>accountName=' . $accountName . '</p>';
  echo'<p>caseId=' . $caseId . '</p>';     

  foreach($case->Tasks->records as $record) {
   $taskId=$record->Id;
   $taskType=$record->Activity_Type__c;
   $taskDate=$record->ActivityDate;
   echo'<p>taskId=' . $taskId . '</p>';
   echo'<p>taskType=' . $taskType . '</p>';
   echo'<p>taskDate=' . $taskDate . '</p>';
  }
  print_r($case);
```

Which returns

```
AccountId=0016000000NsN3uAAF

accountName=budcrossfordfd

caseId=5000e00001J7KtpAAF



Notice:  Undefined property: stdClass::$Tasks in Z:\web\phpToolKit\test\partner.php on line 69



Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in Z:\web\phpToolKit\test\partner.php on line 69



Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Z:\web\phpToolKit\test\partner.php on line 69
```

It looks like "Tasks" isn't the name of the obj, but I can't figure out what it would be instead!
I used: [Salesforce PHP Toolkit - pullup data from nested SOQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45061150/salesforce-php-toolkit-pullup-data-from-nested-soql-query?rq=1) 
for my second example

Comment: `$case->Tasks` doesn't exist in the object given, but `$case->any->Tasks` does.

Comment: I updated it to:
`foreach($case->any->Tasks->records as $record) {`

However i still get response:
`Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: Ahh, `any` is an array, not an object. So then: `$case->any['Tasks']`

Comment: IT WORKED! THANK YOU !
`foreach($case->any['Tasks']->records as $record) {
       $taskId=$record->Id[0];`
Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

I used Sammitch's answer and updated the code to:

```
foreach($queryResult->records as $case){     
  $accountId = $queryResult->current()->AccountId; //Pulls accountId from Query
  $accountName=$queryResult->current()->Service_Account_DMKT__r->Name; //pulls the name of the account the case exists on, note that when we use XXX__r.XXX, we sep. this in PHP with ->
  $caseId= $queryResult->current()->Id; //Pulls CaseId from Query     
  echo'<p>AccountId=' . $accountId . '</p>';
  echo'<p>accountName=' . $accountName . '</p>';
  echo'<p>caseId=' . $caseId . '</p>';     

  foreach($case->any['Tasks']->records as $record) {
   $taskId=$record->Id[0]; //This correctly returns the first ID in the array
   //$taskType=$record->Activity_Type__c; //This doesn't work because this information  is located in a different sub obj "any"
   //$taskDate=$record->ActivityDate; //This also doesn't work because it's located in a sub object "any"
   echo'<p>taskId=' . $taskId . '</p>';
  echo '<p>' . $record->any . '</p>' //watch out, this object might look to only be a string, but there is a lot of white space info in here. you can see it by wrapping it in json_encode($record->any).
  }
  print_r($case);
```

I used the above code, and then I was able to compare a string against it by using strpos to ask the obj if it contained a specific string. This can be really confusing so watch out!